# How do you update a value for a fetched column in MYSQL PDO using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I update a value in a column I have extracted and selected for MySQL PDO. My current code now.

```
    if ($submitcode != $dbcode)
  {
  $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `members` WHERE `username` = :username");
  $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
  $status = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0) // ((I want this selected column for status value to change to 1.))
  die('Some error message');
  }
```

Comment: The same way you `select` but with an `update`.

Comment: @chris85 I apologize I'm very new to this could you please show me example?

Comment: Something like `$SQL = $odb -> prepare("update members set \`status\` = 'new status''  WHERE \`username\` = :username");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($submitcode != $dbcode)
{
$sql = "UPDATE `members` SET `status` = :status WHERE `username` = :username";

//Prepare UPDATE SQL statement.
$statement = $odb->prepare($sql);

$status = 1;

$statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
$statement->bindValue(':status', $status);

//Execute UPDATE statement.
$update = $statement->execute();

}
```

Comment: It is in case if you don't have db connect before but if you have you can skip that part.

Comment: you can use it like this